# Change only the text of an anchor javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple script which will change the text of a number of anchors on a page. I'm quite new to Javascript and I'm able to change the anchors but it changes the whole tag including removing the href.

How do I edit just the text only without affecting the href?

```
<body>
   <div class="loop-add-to-cart">
      <a href="/?preview_id=10822&#038;preview_nonce=2f9a98329f&#038;_thumbnail_id=-1&#038;preview=true&#038;add-to-cart=11544" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="11544" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple ajax_add_to_cart">Add to basket</a>    
      <div class="wpd-buttons-wrap-simple" data-id="11544">
         <a href="http://802.f5f.myftpupload.com/11550-2/design/11544/" class="mg-top-10 wpc-customize-product">Design from blank</a>                  
      </div>
   </div>
   <script>
      function buybuttons() {
          var buybuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('wpd-buttons-wrap-simple');
          for(var i = 0; i < buybuttons.length; i++){
              buybuttons[i].innerHTML="Test";
          };
      }

      buybuttons();
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how you are grabbing the anchors? Look at innerHTML - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: You are changing the `innerHTML` of the `div`, not the `a`. Use `document.querySelectorAll(".wpd-buttons-wrap-simple a")`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rLrpv0n1/

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query selector to get all `a` tags inside an element with a class of `wpd-buttons-wrap-simple`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.wpd-buttons-wrap-simple a');
```

You can then set the `textContent` or `innerHTML` of the link.

```html
<body>
   <div class="loop-add-to-cart">
      <a href="/?preview_id=10822&#038;preview_nonce=2f9a98329f&#038;_thumbnail_id=-1&#038;preview=true&#038;add-to-cart=11544" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="11544" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple ajax_add_to_cart">Add to basket</a>    
      <div class="wpd-buttons-wrap-simple" data-id="11544">
         <a href="http://802.f5f.myftpupload.com/11550-2/design/11544/" class="mg-top-10 wpc-customize-product">Design from blank</a>                  
      </div>
   </div>
   <script>
      function buybuttons() {
          var buybuttons = document.querySelectorAll('.wpd-buttons-wrap-simple a');
          for(var i = 0; i < buybuttons.length; i++){
              buybuttons[i].textContent = "Test";
          };
      }

      buybuttons();
   </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ['querySelectorAll'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you can get the element the class and the element inside as below:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.wpd-buttons-wrap-simple > a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function buybuttons() {
            var buybuttons = document.querySelectorAll('.wpd-buttons-wrap-simple a');
            for(var i = 0; i < buybuttons.length; i++){
                buybuttons[i].innerHTML="Test";
            };
        }


buybuttons();
```

You are currently overwriting the innerHTML of the div element, but you are looking for the anchor element inside of the div.

Use document.querySelectorAll to get all of them, or document.querySelector to only get the first.